# How to import RxJs main namespace 'rxjs' into TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am creating simple app in Typescript. I'd like to use RxJs in it. Typically in browser, as the docs for RxJs say, if I used CDN, I would have `rxjs` namespace available in global scope. Then I'd have possibility to decompose it this way:

```
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
```

... and that's all to use it (eg. `fromEvent(button, 'click').pipe(...)` and so on). As I am writing an app for desktop use (with electron), I installed rxjs via `npm install rxjs`. And here I am stuck. No matter which way I try to import it to my .ts file, it results in errors like "Type (...) has no property/no exported member fromEvent" or similar. I tried:

- `import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';`
- `import { rxjs } from 'rxjs';`
- `import { rxjs } from 'rxjs/Rx';`
- `import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';`
- `import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/Rx';`
- `import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/fromEvent';`

but none of them worked. I tried also `declare var rxjs`, and it worked, but actually what is the point of using statically typed language if we lose this way all information of types and cannot use type checking (as far as I made research, RxJs itself is written in Typescript, so it shouldn't be problem to import all type information)?

Maybe it's a stupid question and I should totally change my way of thinking of it, if it is so - please correct me, but how can I import `rxjs` namespace to  typescript? So I could write same code as I would write in .js in browser?

Comment: You are telling us that `import * as rxjs from 'rxjs'; const { fromEvent } = rxjs;` did not work?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you a little bit, to put it clear, this actually worked, but in next line I import ```const { scan } = rxjs.operators;``` and this one fails (Property 'operators' does not exist on type 'node_modules/rxjs/index')

Comment: Which is true. Try `rxjs.scan`...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs < click the stable link and see source in github, then look for the objects you want and see how they are exported and by which package.

Comment: I tried ```import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';``` and then ```rxjs.scan``` and I still get the same error message. What's even more surprising, I tried also ```import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators'``` and then I got a bunch of errors in internal rxjs' .d.ts files (eg. Observable.d.ts 'Promise' 82:59 error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here). But basically what I ment is to possibly import rxjs the same way in Typescript as when I code in .js in browser (and the same way the examples in official rxjs docs are written)